# How to parse out each Chinese character?

Tags: objective-c

Given a sentence composing of X number of Chinese characters. I want to parse each character out in Objective-C or C++.

I tried:

```
NSString * nsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"你好吗"];
for (int i = 0; i < [nsText length]; i++) 
{
  char current = [nsText characterAtIndex:i];
  printf("%i: %c\n", i, current);
}
```

But I'm not getting the right characters, I got index 0 = ', index 1 = }, etc. The length is returned correctly, which equals 3. I need UTF8 encoding to display it to the UI.

Any tips will be helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things wrong. First, `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, which is bigger than the `char` to which you're assigning. You're losing information there. Second, `%c` is the format specifier for printing an ASCII value (8 bits). You want `%C` (uppercase 'C') to print a 16-bit `unichar`. Finally, `printf()` doesn't seem to accept `%C`, so you need to use `NSLog()` instead. Rewritten, then, we have:

```
NSString * nsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"你好吗"];
for (int i = 0; i < [nsText length]; i++) 
{
    unichar current = [nsText characterAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%i: %C\n", i, current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this solve your problem?

```
NSString * nsText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"你好吗"];
for (int i = 0; i < [nsText length]; i++) {
    NSString *str = [nsText substringToIndex:i+1];
    NSString *str2 =[str substringFromIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",str2);
}
```